# Audio Recorder not working in iphone with ios 7

Tags: ios, iphone, ios7, avfoundation

I am facing problem with AVFoundation framework. my app is  all ready made in older version then I upgrade into ios 7 this time my audio recorder is working on simulator but not working on iphone. so anyone help me what is actual problem .

my code is this

```
-(IBAction)startRecording
{
    btnRecord.showsTouchWhenHighlighted = YES;
    btnRecord.enabled = NO;
    btnPlay.enabled = NO;
    btnStop.enabled = YES;
    btnPause.enabled = YES;
    btnDelete.enabled = NO;
    if(!flagPause)
    {
        NSDateFormatter *dateFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
        [dateFormat setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd"];

        NSDateFormatter *timeFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
        [timeFormat setDateFormat:@"HH.mm.SS"];

        NSDate *now = [[NSDate alloc] init];

        theDate = [dateFormat stringFromDate:now];
        theTime = [timeFormat stringFromDate:now];


        NSString *filename =[NSString stringWithFormat:@"|%@|%@|",theDate,theTime];
        theDate=[[NSString alloc]initWithString:filename];


        AVAudioSession *audioSession = [AVAudioSession sharedInstance];
        [audioSession setCategory:AVAudioSessionCategoryRecord error:nil];

        *****  i try this one but not working
        //[audioSession setCategory:AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayAndRecord error:nil];
        //[audioSession setActive:YES error:nil];


        NSMutableDictionary *recordSettings = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] initWithCapacity:10];

        if(recordEncoding == ENC_PCM)
        {
            [recordSettings setObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt: kAudioFormatLinearPCM] forKey: AVFormatIDKey];
            [recordSettings setObject:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:44100.0] forKey: AVSampleRateKey];
            [recordSettings setObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:2] forKey:AVNumberOfChannelsKey];
            [recordSettings setObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:16] forKey:AVLinearPCMBitDepthKey];
            [recordSettings setObject:[NSNumber numberWithBool:NO] forKey:AVLinearPCMIsBigEndianKey];
            [recordSettings setObject:[NSNumber numberWithBool:NO] forKey:AVLinearPCMIsFloatKey];     
        }
        else
        {
            NSNumber *formatObject;
            switch (recordEncoding) 
            {
                case (ENC_AAC): 
                    formatObject = [NSNumber numberWithInt: kAudioFormatMPEG4AAC];
                    break;
                case (ENC_ALAC):
                    formatObject = [NSNumber numberWithInt: kAudioFormatAppleLossless];
                    break;
                case (ENC_IMA4):
                    formatObject = [NSNumber numberWithInt: kAudioFormatAppleIMA4];
                    break;
                case (ENC_ILBC):
                    formatObject = [NSNumber numberWithInt: kAudioFormatiLBC];
                    break;
                case (ENC_ULAW):
                    formatObject = [NSNumber numberWithInt: kAudioFormatULaw];
                    break;
                default:
                    formatObject = [NSNumber numberWithInt: kAudioFormatAppleIMA4];
            }
            [recordSettings setObject:formatObject forKey: AVFormatIDKey];
            [recordSettings setObject:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:44100.0] forKey: AVSampleRateKey];
            [recordSettings setObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:2] forKey:AVNumberOfChannelsKey];
            [recordSettings setObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:12800] forKey:AVEncoderBitRateKey];

            //**************** I try this one ***********************>>>>
            //[recordSettings setObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:12800] forKey:AVEncoderBitRateKey];

            [recordSettings setObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:16] forKey:AVLinearPCMBitDepthKey];

            [recordSettings setObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt: AVAudioQualityHigh] forKey: AVEncoderAudioQualityKey];
        }
        NSURL *url;
        NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES); 
        NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0]; // Get documents folder
        NSString *dataPath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Recording"];
        if (![[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:dataPath])
            [[NSFileManager defaultManager] createDirectoryAtPath:dataPath withIntermediateDirectories:NO attributes:nil error:nil];

        NSString *filePath =[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/%@.caf",dataPath,theDate];
        // appiPhone.strATitle = theDate;
        url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:filePath];
        NSError *error = nil;

        audioRecorder = [[ AVAudioRecorder alloc] initWithURL:url settings:recordSettings error:&error];

        if ([audioRecorder prepareToRecord] == YES)
        {
            [audioRecorder record];
        }
        else 
        {
            //int errorCode = CFSwapInt32HostToBig ([error code]); 
            // NSLog(@"Error: %@ [%4.4s])" , [error localizedDescription], (char*)&errorCode);      
        }
    }
    else 
    {
        [audioRecorder record];
        flagPause = NO;
    }
    //appiPhone.intBtnAnsTag = 1;
}
```

Comment: This is not an answer for this question but as per my observation you have set AVNumberOfChannelsKey to 2. Can you clarify its need? Otherwise its OK to keep it 1. It will increase the quality of recording.

Comment: you can't listen sounds but probably it records..if it works on simulator, try listen when you play your recorded sound to the iphone earpiece speaker..

Comment: One of the differences between 6 and 7 is that permission is required to access the Microphone. Check you have granted permission to the app. Look in  Settings->Privacy->Microphone

Answer (score 0):

I recently developed a very simple play and record demo (literally just 3 buttons doing what you expect).  I initially had the same problem: it would work in iOS simulator but not on my device.  First I had to make sure the app had permission to use the mic by going to settings -> privacy -> microphone

I also had to had the following code before setting up my audio recorder

```
 AVAudioSession *session = [AVAudioSession sharedInstance];
[session setCategory:AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayAndRecord error:nil];
[session setActive:YES error:nil];
```

Below is the entire code of my super simple demo. AudioPlayer and AudioRecorder are called out in the .h

```
#import "ViewController.h"

@interface ViewController ()

@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    AVAudioSession *session = [AVAudioSession sharedInstance];
    [session setCategory:AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayAndRecord error:nil];
    [session setActive:YES error:nil];
    NSDictionary *audioSettings = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:44100],AVSampleRateKey,[NSNumber numberWithInt:kAudioFormatAppleLossless], AVFormatIDKey, [NSNumber numberWithInt:1],AVNumberOfChannelsKey, [NSNumber numberWithInt:AVAudioQualityMedium], AVEncoderAudioQualityKey, nil];

    NSURL *audioFileURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[NSTemporaryDirectory() stringByAppendingString:@"audioRecording.m4a"]];

    self.audioRecorder = [[AVAudioRecorder alloc]initWithURL:audioFileURL settings:audioSettings error:nil];

   [super viewDidLoad];
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

- (IBAction)audioRecord:(id)sender {

    [self.audioRecorder record];
}

- (IBAction)audioStop:(id)sender {
    [self.audioPlayer stop];
    [self.audioRecorder stop];

    NSURL *audioFileURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[NSTemporaryDirectory() stringByAppendingString:@"audioRecording.m4a"]];
    self.audioPlayer = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:audioFileURL error:nil];
}

- (IBAction)audioPlay:(id)sender {

    [self.audioPlayer play];
}
@end
```